# Pandas read_csv inconsistent with data inference

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm building out a function that reads csv data of unknown format from an S3 bucket. If I read a column of data that entirely filled, the dataframe infers the datatype correctly, however it always converts the datatype to a string if any row within the column is empty. For example:

```
csv_1 = """id,name,age
    0,dan,10
    1,ana,
    """

csv_2 = """id,name,age
    3,bill,33
    4,jill,35
    """

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_1), index_col=None, keep_default_na=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_2), index_col=None, keep_default_na=False)

df1['age'][0] # '10'
df2['age'][0] # 33
```

Is there a way to change this behavior to make the datatype of a given column default to what the rest of the column is, which in this case is an integer? I can't hard code conversions of specific columns since I do not know the columns or datatypes before ingestion and should work for any csv structure.

Comment: Pretty sure `df1 = pd.read_csv(csv_1, index_col=None, keep_default_na=False)` fails, you'd have to wrap it in a `io.StringIO` buffer

Comment: Anyway... I think you just want to omit `keep_default_na=False` and it will do what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `keep_default_na=False`, which means you get the following behavior:

> If `keep_default_na` is False, and `na_values` are not specified, no
> strings will be parsed as NaN.

So in this case, that empty value is being interpreted as an empty string, `''` which will no longer be treated as NaN, thus, it treats the whole column as a string.

So just don't add that argument, keep the default `keep_default_na=True`:

```
In [12]: df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_1), index_col=None)

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
   id name   age
0   0  dan  10.0
1   1  ana   NaN
```

Comment: This is still changing the data type of the age column since it should still be an integer, which unfortunately causes other issues in the program, such as changing `id` columns into scientific notation occasionally.

Comment: @CoopTang that's because you can't have `NaN` and `int`. That's a well-known limitation of pandas. There are experimental features which would allow this... What value do you *want* there?

Comment: My preference would be to keep the data type that has already been seen given the assumption that a column can only be one data type (i.e. `string`, `int`, `float`) or `NaN`. So in my example, I'd like the `age` column to be of type `int`.

Comment: @CoopTang but what would the value be for `df1['age'][1]`? There is no `NaN` in `np.int` data types. You could use the experimental `pd.Int64` type, which is nullable, but I don't think `pd.read_csv` will infer that type, you would have to do it explicitly, which is what you are trying to avoid, no?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not super familiar with pandas and all of its data types. `pd.Int64` would be totally fine, I'm just wanting to preserve the data types in the csv if there is ever a `NaN` in a column. So if the column was intended to be `floats`, or the pandas version of `float`, then I want that column to be `float` even if there is a single row that has `NaN` as a value. Likewise for the other supported data types like `int` or `string`.

Comment: @CoopTang as I've explained, `pd.Int64` is experimental, it isn't supported in `pd.read_csv` as far as I can tell, that is, it won't be inferred. So you'd have to do the conversion "hard coded" as you stated in your question that you can't do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228266/discussion-between-juanpa-arrivillaga-and-cooptang).